# rearranging Powers

Tags: power-series

I' just so stumped right now. I want to get $x^{n}$ to equal $x^{2n+1}$. Right now I have that:
$$(\sqrt{x})^{2n} = x^n$$
But I don't know what to do to x to get:
$$x^n = \{\text{something done to $x$}\}^{2n+1}$$

Comment: \begin{eqnarray*}
\left( x^{\frac{n}{2n+1}} \right)^{2n+1}
\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: $\left(x^{\frac n{2n+1}}\right)^{2n+1}=x^n$ and this is pretty much as simple as it gets.

Comment: @G is there a way to have x not involving x like
$$x^{\frac{n}{2n+1}}$$

Comment: @M.Turner To what end? It's **that** thing, regardless of how you write it. Would, I don't know, $\exp\left(\frac n{2n+1}\ln x\right)$ better suit your taste?

Comment: @G no no. See my comment below and you'll see what I'm trying to do

Comment: You should have written it in the question to begin with, instead of playing the guessing game with strangers. Multiply the series by $\dfrac{\lvert x\rvert^{1/2}}{\lvert x\rvert^{1/2}}$ and set $y=\lvert x\rvert^{1/2}$. Be careful of the sign, though.

Comment: @G I'm still not getting it. I want to know what $\sin(\text{something})$ to get the series below?

Answer (score 1):

Recall the following exponent law:

$$x^{ab} = (x^a)^b$$

In your case, you have this:

$$x^n = (x^a)^{2n+1}$$

Note that this is just a more mathematical way of stating exactly what you have in your question:

> But I don't know what to do to x to get:
>   $$x^n = \{\text{something done to $x$}\}^{2n+1}$$

So for your particular problem, you have $ab = n$ and $b = 2n+1$, and you want to find the value of $a$ that makes all of this work.  Well, since you know $ab = n$, then $a = n/b$, and since you know $b = 2n+1$, then we can conclude $a = \dfrac n{2n+1}$.

$$ x^n = \left(x^{\frac n{2n+1}}\right)^{2n+1} $$

Comment: Damn. I need to express
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n x^n}{(2n+1)!}$$
In terms of sine? and sine has $x^{2n+1}$ not $x^n$ so I'm super stuck

Comment: @M.Turner, I think you should update your original question to reflect exactly what it is you were asked to do at the very beginning of whatever led you to this requirement.

Answer (score 0):

$(x^n)=x^{\frac{n}{2n+1}^{2n+1}}$ $\forall n\in\Bbb R/\{-\frac{1}{2}$}